# Problems Serializing form data and submitting it to the control with mapping

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that is flexible. Meaning that depending on what selection you make in a dropdownlist the fields will be different.  Also, the controller action that is called will also change.  I am trying to get this to work with just a simple example, but I can't find how to submit data to the controller and have the controller map it correctly to a defined class.

**Clarification:**  When a user creates a new question that has only one choice this is the form/controller that they are using.  However, when they create a question with multiple choices I would like to use the same form/controller.  The error i am getting is that the object is null.  Which i think means that whenever the data is being passed to the controller, it is not being properly mapped into the object.  How can i map the data explicitly into my defined object? Or should i do this whole thing differently?

Here is the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateSimpleQuestion(SimpleQuestion question)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            question.question.is_counted = true;
            question.question.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            db.Questions.Add(question.question);
            db.QuestionChoices.Add(question.choices[0]);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(question);
    }
```

Here is the class:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class SimpleQuestion
    {
        public Question question { get; set; }

        public QuestionChoices[] choices { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the script that is calling the controller action:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("form").on("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = $('form').serialize();
        console.log(data);
        $.post('/Question/CreateSimpleQuestion/', data);
    });
</script>
```

This is the serialized data:

> QuestionTitle=faketitle&Keywords=fakekeywords&Description=fakedescription&Comments=fakecomments&QuestionType=Simple&DisplayText=fakequestiontext&OrderNumber=fakeorder

And in case you need the specifics of the model:

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    public string QuestionTitle { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public string QuestionType { get; set; }

    public string Keywords { get; set; }

    public bool is_counted { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
    [MaxLength]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
    [MaxLength]
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    //These define a one to many relationship
    public virtual ICollection<TeamQuestionRoster> TeamQuestionRosters { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Response> Responses { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QuestionChoices> QuestionChoices { get; set; }
}



public class QuestionChoices
{
    public int QuestionChoicesId { get; set; }

    public string DisplayText { get; set; }

    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }

    public bool is_correct { get; set; }

    //These are the FK properties
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    //This defines the FK Relationships
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }

    //These define a one to many relationship
    public virtual ICollection<ResponseDetails> ResponsDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your problem? I think that your are trying to have a single route for all permeations of your "flexible" form but possibly have different processing based on the object received. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. Let me know if i need to give a better example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be having a issue with your media type. Try posting JSON like this:

```
$.post('/Question/CreateSimpleQuestion', data, function() { /* success callback */ }, 'application/json');
```

EDIT: 
The `$.post` shorthand method might be expecting `'json'` rather than `'application/json'`. I typically use `$.ajax` instead.

TAKE 2:
Based the JSON you posted, I can see that your data is not being serialized properly. You're getting name/value pairs instead of actual JSON objects. Your JSON data should like this:

```
{
    "QuestionId" : 0, 
    "QuestionTitle" : "My Title",
    "Description": "My Description"
}
```

Here's another SO post explaining how to convert the jQuery serialize results to an appropriate JSON object: [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I'm not sending it as JSON, but I think i am going to try that. `json.stringify`

Comment: Still not working: `<b> Exception Details: </b>System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.<br><br>`

Comment: Here is the data that is being sent to the controller: {"name":"QuestionTitle","value":"Test5 with jquery"},{"name":"Keywords","value":"(keywords)"},{"name":"Description","value":"question"},{"name":"Comments","value":"comment"},{"name":"QuestionType","value":"Simple"},{"name":"DisplayText","value":"hi"},{"name":"OrderNumber","value":"1"},

Comment: Please see my revised answer.

Comment: I think that its getting closer to the right answer, but its still not serializing it correctly. `{
"QuestionTitle":["newQuestion",""],
"Keywords":"Partial",
"Description":"question",
"Comments":"comment",
"QuestionType":["Simple","Simple"],
"DisplayText":"hi",
"OrderNumber":"1"
}`   I'm not sure why its submitting two values in title and type.  Also Display text and OrderNumber should be nested with a parent field of choice.... or something like that.

Comment: Here is a link to the test site.... Most links don't work yet, but click on the create tab to get to the form.  https://drive0.azurewebsites.net/question

Comment: Do you happen to have duplicate form elements rendered? That would explain the array values being supplied. Try building a proper JSON element by hand and see if your model isn't null in the controller. From there, you just need to determine where your serialization issues are.

Comment: I've stared at this too long to see the mistakes. I checked for duplicates, but i didn't see any.  I prolly just passed over them. **Edit** Fixed that issue.